# Wine Installation Error

Tags: wine

I tried installing `Wine` using the terminal and I got a message to accept, and so I tried pressing the `OK` button in the terminal but it didn't work. Then I forced the terminal to close and tried the process again but I still got an error.

So then I tried `Ubuntu Software Center`. When using that I got a message to accept the terms and conditions and I also accepted that. And then I went on installing and then it suddenly stopped. I waited for an hour but it was stuck....

When I tried the procedure again it showed that it was installing but the process bar was still on zero. Does anyone know what the problem is here?

Comment: If you were to install wine via the terminal, you need to press the "Tab" key till you get to the "OK" button and press "Enter" to be able to continue with the installation.

Answer (score 2):

Open up a terminal and type

```
apt-get --purge remove wine
```

This may not do anything but it should remove any parts of wine that may have been incorrectly installed.

Then to install wine type

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install wine1.5
```

Comment: Hey thanks buddy I found out a way and it works now....Anyways that guys!!!!